# pdfbox image gets blurred when digitally signing a pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have created a utility to digitally sign pdf files using pdfbox library everything works perfectly except that the image that I use as the face image for the signature appears as dithered when the pdf document is opened after signing, if I open the image separately it appears to be fine, I have also tried to generate the signature field face image at run time and the same thing happens with it also.
Any help/pointers will be great.
TIA

Comment: Please mention the version, and attach link to the image and to the result PDF.

Comment: Indeed, please supply data to analyze. Also show how exactly you use the image in signing and mention the viewer in which the bad quality can be observed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the version of pdfbox is 2.0.8
link for image:-https://ibb.co/6tRkWV7
Viewer: Adobe Acrobat

Comment: @mkl:-the version of pdfbox is 2.0.8 link for image:-ibb.co/6tRkWV7 Viewer: Adobe Acrobat

Comment: We need the PDF too. The current PDFBox version is 2.0.20. Don't use old versions.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr this code was written much earlier but nobody paid attention to this fact
link for sample pdf file:-https://easyupload.io/lxnvi6

Answer (score 1):

The image you linked has a 200x45 pixel size:

[image]

The image in the PDF has a 180x50 pixel size:

[image]

Apparently the original tick has been scaled somewhat before being used for the image in the PDF.

Scaling bitmap images, in particular if not done by a power of 2, makes them blurry, especially in case of so small images.

Thus, if you want to prevent the blurriness, don't scale like this.

PDFBox does not create such images with writing. Thus, this must be done by some other code in your signing utility.